# $1+\frac{1}{(N-1)²}+\frac{1}{(N+1)²}+\frac{1}{(2N-1)²}+\frac{1}{(2N+1)²}+...$ series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to know if there are references on the integral

$1+\frac{1}{(N-1)²}+\frac{1}{(N+1)²}+\frac{1}{(2N-1)²}+\frac{1}{(2N+1)²}+...$
N is a natural number greatest 2

Comment: Do you mean $n\geq 2$?

Answer (score 2):

$$ 
\begin{align} 
\color{red}{S}&=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(kN-1)^2}\,+\,\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(kN+1)^2} \\[2mm] 
&=1+\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k-1/N)^2}\,+\,\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+1/N)^2} \\[2mm] 
&=1+\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k\color{red}{-1+1}-1/N)^2}\,+\,\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k\color{red}{-1+1}+1/N)^2} \\[2mm] 
&=1+\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{k=\color{red}{0}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+(1-1/N))^2}\,+\,\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{k=\color{red}{0}}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(k+(1+1/N))^2} \\[2mm] 
&=\color{red}{1+\frac{1}{N^2}\left[\,\zeta\left(2,1-\frac{1}{N}\right)+\zeta\left(2,1+\frac{1}{N}\right)\,\right]} 
\end{align} 
$$ 
[Hurwitz Zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function)

Answer (score 1):

*Similar to Hazem Orabi's answer.*

$${S}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(kN-1)^2}\,+\,\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(kN+1)^2}  $$
$$S=1+\frac{\psi ^{(1)}\left(1-\frac{1}{N}\right)}{N^2}+\frac{\psi ^{(1)}\left(1+\frac{1}{N}\right)}{N^2}=\color{blue}{\frac{\pi ^2 }{N^2}\csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi }{N}\right)}$$

from the identity
$$\psi ^{(1)}(1-a)+\psi ^{(1)}(1+a)=\pi ^2 \csc ^2(\pi  a)-\frac{1}{a^2}$$

Comment: From the identity $\,{\displaystyle\psi^{(m)}(s)=(-1)^{m+1}\,m!\,\zeta(m+1,s)}\,$ of [Polygamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function). Nice finish, (+1).